# Редирект change() jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

```
<select id="sel_nav">
            <option data-hr="google.com">1</option>
            <option data-hr="">2</option>
            <option data-hr="">3</option>
            <option data-hr="">4</option>
            <option data-hr="" selected="selected">5</option>
            <option data-hr="">6</option>
        </select>

$('#sel_nav').change(function() {
        window.location = $(this).data('hr');
    });
```

Привет. Я не могу никак понять, почему меня перенаправляет на undefined? Если `$(this).val()`, то все ок... Помогите исправить плиз.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому, что у select нет атрибута data

```
$('#sel_nav').change(function() {
    window.location.href = $('option:selected',this).data('hr');
});
```